# Backdating a wagtail page

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to repost content posted to a third party website to our own Wagtail instance, and to prevent this content from showing up as "new content", need to backdate each post. However, there does not appear to be anything in the Wagtail UI that allows for this: is this something that needs to be done either programmatically via Python, or through manual DB queries that update the wagtail_pages table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the **first_published_at** field to your Page editing interface.

You could add it to your settings_panels for your custom Page model:

```py
class Example(Page):
    ...
    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
        FieldPanel('first_published_at')
    ]
    ...
```

In these cases it's quite useful to look at the original Wagtail Page model, you can see that the first_published_at field is available, and editable so there's nothing stopping you from adding it to the editing interface:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f12d01f88f7d4e09e2b58c0419c2bbee8a40a8a6/wagtail/core/models.py#L297